# To install matplotlib from source, what is the source tree

Tags: matplotlib, installation

I am trying to use the module "plot_trisurf()" in matplotlib. My python compile gives an error that axes3D does not contain the module. I want to install the latest version of matplotlib.

I would like to use the steps provided here: http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html

In source install, step 2 is "delete the build directory in source tree". What is the source tree and where do i find the right build directory to delete?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: How did you get the current source?  If you have never built the source before, there will not be a build tree to delete.

Comment: I never built the source before. I am using python pre-installed in ubuntu. Does that mean that I don't have to bother with the delete "build" directory step? - Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source tree is under what ever directory you clone the `git` repo into or unpack the tarball into.  It will contain a whole bunch (~30) of folders and files including `lib`, `CXX`, and `INSTALL`.  If you have previously built `matplotlib` there will be a folder `build` where the results of the build are stored, if you have not yet run your first build it will not exist.

If you have cloned the `git` repo the following:

```
git clean -f -d -x
```

will remove any untracked files for you.